# What makes Rest different from RPC in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, rpc

We usually follow the MVC pattern while creating Rest API. I Often Confuse this sometimes with RPC since people tell me it should be in Http format and Making a CRUD operation from Spring boot does not make it Rest API. So, I want to know whether RPC is similar to Rest API or not?

Comment: https://nordicapis.com/whats-the-difference-between-rpc-and-rest/#:~:text=The%20most%20fundamental%20difference%20between,handling%20large%20quantities%20of%20data.

Answer (score 5):

**REST**

> Representational state transfer (REST) is a software architectural
> style that was created to guide the design and development of the
> architecture for the World Wide Web. REST defines a set of constraints
> for how the architecture of an Internet-scale distributed hypermedia
> system, such as the Web, should behave.
>
> REST is defined by resources that encapsulate entities.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

**RPC**

> In distributed computing, a remote procedure call (RPC) is when a
> computer program causes a procedure (subroutine) to execute in a
> different address space (commonly on another computer on a shared
> network), which is coded as if it were a normal (local) procedure
> call, without the programmer explicitly coding the details for the
> remote interaction.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

**Difference**

With REST every resource has an address (URL) and a representation (for example JSON) and the resources are accessed using HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT etc).

In RPC you want to call a procedure/method. A typical protocol will be SOAP where you always use POST requests with a XML protocol with a header and body.